# How do I (programmatically) get a list of Snowflake's reserved words?

Tags: python, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Snowflake maintains a list of reserved words within their [documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/reserved-keywords.html); however, I need a way to cleanly (I.E. without scraping it) and programmatically check against this list. I'd assume they make this queryable somewhere, but I can't find any information on it.

Update:
Opened this on [Snowflake Ideas](https://community.snowflake.com/s/ideas) (can't seem to link post - just search "Expose Reserved Words in a Queryable Table")

Comment: I wish database would produce this. Even though the JDBC standard provides an API for it, it's seldom implemented; ...and when implemented it's outdated for 10 years easily. Since rarely anyone uses it, database developers don't really pay too much attention to it. Maybe you can file a ticket, so they can update it.

Answer (score 1):

Snowflake updates all the reserved words in its link
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/reserved-keywords.html

Other than this , as of now it has no publicly exposed query for users to query against.
You could however open a request for such a feature in the 'Snowflake Ideas' page

https://community.snowflake.com/s/ideas

Comment: Thanks, added the Idea (and updated my question to link to that)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way is to simply pull that HTML table from the snowflake documentation and create your own list. Excel is one method. You can "Insert data from Web", then use `TEXTJOIN()` on the range to create a list of the keywords. This gets me this list that you can use in a regex

```
((ACCOUNT)|(ALL)|(ALTER)|(AND)|(ANY)|(AS)|(BETWEEN)|(BY)|(CASE)|(CAST)|(CHECK)|(COLUMN)|(CONNECT)|(CONNECTION)|(CONSTRAINT)|(CREATE)|(CROSS)|(CURRENT)|(CURRENT_DATE)|(CURRENT_TIME)|(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)|(CURRENT_USER)|(DATABASE)|(DELETE)|(DISTINCT)|(DROP)|(ELSE)|(EXISTS)|(FALSE)|(FOLLOWING)|(FOR)|(FROM)|(FULL)|(GRANT)|(GROUP)|(GSCLUSTER)|(HAVING)|(ILIKE)|(IN)|(INCREMENT)|(INNER)|(INSERT)|(INTERSECT)|(INTO)|(IS)|(ISSUE)|(JOIN)|(LATERAL)|(LEFT)|(LIKE)|(LOCALTIME)|(LOCALTIMESTAMP)|(MINUS)|(NATURAL)|(NOT)|(NULL)|(OF)|(ON)|(OR)|(ORDER)|(ORGANIZATION)|(QUALIFY)|(REGEXP)|(REVOKE)|(RIGHT)|(RLIKE)|(ROW)|(ROWS)|(SAMPLE)|(SCHEMA)|(SELECT)|(SET)|(SOME)|(START)|(TABLE)|(TABLESAMPLE)|(THEN)|(TO)|(TRIGGER)|(TRUE)|(TRY_CAST)|(UNION)|(UNIQUE)|(UPDATE)|(USING)|(VALUES)|(VIEW)|(WHEN)|(WHENEVER)|(WHERE)|(WITH))
```

or in SQL

```
SELECT * FROM (VALUES 
     ('ACCOUNT')
    ,('ALL')
    ,('AND')
    ,('ANY')
    ,('AS')
    ,('BETWEEN')
    ,('BY')
    ,('CASE')
    ,('CAST')
    ,('CHECK')
    ,('COLUMN')
    ,('CONNECT')
    ,('CONNECTION')
    ,('CROSS')
    ,('DATABASE')
    ,('DELETE')
    ,('DISTINCT')
    ,('ELSE')
    ,('EXISTS')
    ,('FALSE')
    ,('FOLLOWING')
    ,('FOR')
    ,('FROM')
    ,('FULL')
    ,('GRANT')
    ,('GROUP')
    ,('GSCLUSTER')
    ,('HAVING')
    ,('ILIKE')
    ,('IN')
    ,('INCREMENT')
    ,('INNER')
    ,('INSERT')
    ,('INTERSECT')
    ,('INTO')
    ,('IS')
    ,('ISSUE')
    ,('JOIN')
    ,('LATERAL')
    ,('LEFT')
    ,('LIKE')
    ,('LOCALTIME')
    ,('LOCALTIMESTAMP')
    ,('MINUS')
    ,('NATURAL')
    ,('OF')
    ,('ON')
    ,('OR')
    ,('ORDER')
    ,('ORGANIZATION')
    ,('QUALIFY')
    ,('REGEXP')
    ,('REVOKE')
    ,('RIGHT')
    ,('RLIKE')
    ,('ROW')
    ,('ROWS')
    ,('SAMPLE')
    ,('SELECT')
    ,('SET')
    ,('SOME')
    ,('START')
    ,('TABLESAMPLE')
    ,('THEN')
    ,('TO')
    ,('TRIGGER')
    ,('TRUE')
    ,('TRY_CAST')
    ,('UNION')
    ,('UNIQUE')
    ,('UPDATE')
    ,('USING')
    ,('VALUES')
    ,('VIEW')
    ,('WHEN')
    ,('WHENEVER')
    ,('WHERE')
    ,('WITH')
) AS SNOWFLAKE_RESERVED_WORDS(SNOWFLAKE_RESERVED_WORD)
```

Comment: I do wonder why Snowflake has so many reserved words as (at least some) other SQL DBMSes are able to parse DDL and DML with (almost) all of the above words not needed to be quoted when used as identifiers. Oh well.