# Get snowflake reserved keywords

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there any way to get `snowflake-reserved keywords` using Apis or Query?

I have tried to take the keywords from html page but i am looking for Apis or Query.

Comment: you can get that from `https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/reserved-keywords` with `get` request. You have to traverse the page using beautifulsoup

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I (programmatically) get a list of Snowflake's reserved words?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62579330/how-do-i-programmatically-get-a-list-of-snowflakes-reserved-words)

Comment: I have done the same but I'm looking for other approaches.